# Influx db java client batch does not write to DB

Tags: java, influxdb

I am trying to write points to influxDB using their Java client.
Batch is important to me.

If I use the influxDB.enableBatch with influxDB.write(Point) no data is inserted.
If I use the BatchPoints and influxDB.write(batchPoints) - data is inserted successfully.

Both code samples are taken from: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-java/tree/influxdb-java-2.7

```
    InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect(influxUrl, influxUser, influxPassword);
    influxDB.setDatabase(dbName);
    influxDB.setRetentionPolicy("autogen");

    // Flush every 2000 Points, at least every 100ms
    influxDB.enableBatch(2000, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    influxDB.write(Point.measurement("cpu")
            .time(System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .addField("idle", 90L)
            .addField("user", 9L)
            .addField("system", 1L)
            .build());

    Query query = new Query("SELECT idle FROM cpu", dbName);
    QueryResult result = influxDB.query(query);
```

Returns nothing.

```
    BatchPoints batchPoints = BatchPoints.database(dbName).tag("async", "true").build();
    Point point1 = Point
            .measurement("cpu")
            .tag("atag", "test")
            .addField("idle", 90L)
            .addField("usertime", 9L)
            .addField("system", 1L)
            .build();
    batchPoints.point(point1);
    influxDB.write(batchPoints);
    Query query = new Query("SELECT * FROM cpu ", dbName);
    QueryResult result = influxDB.query(query);
```

This returns data successfully.

As mentioned, I need the first way to function.
How can I achieve that?

versions:
influxdb-1.3.6
influxdb-java:2.7

Regards, Ido

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's too late or you have already resolved your issue, but I will answer your question, it may be useful for others.

I think your first example is not working because you enabled batch functionality and it will "Flush every 2000 Points, at least every 100ms". So basically it's working, but you are making select before the actual save is performed.
When you use `influxDB.enableBatch(...);` functionality influxdb-client  creates internal thread pool for storing your data after collecting them or by timeout and it will not be done immediately.

In second example when you use `influxDB.write(batchPoints);` influxdb-client is synchronously writing your data to InfluxDb. That's why your select statement is able to return data immediately.